# Reach External storage AndroidQ

Tags: android, xamarin.android

How I can reach the external storage path, I was using Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath but it's deprecated is there any alternative solution I tried

> GetExternalFilesDir("")

but it returns the data bath for the project

Answer (score 0):

you can try `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "filepath";` to get from external Directory. Hope it works for you.

Comment: it's deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Please Use `GetExternalFilesDir()`, `GetExternalCacheDir()`, or `GetExternalMediaDir()` (methods on Application.Context) instead of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Get the destPath with the new API call:Please use:

`var path=  Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null).AbsolutePath;`

Comment: @AYKHO Are there any update for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this for kotlin:

```
val fileName = "${getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)?.absolutePath}/${UUID.randomUUID()}.png"
```